# Custom drawing WinAPI combobox listbox border

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox, listbox, border

The listbox portion of a standard Win32 dropdown combo box has a 1-px border and a drop shadow. I need to suppress these but haven't been able to.

The frame appears to be drawn during processing of both WM_PRINT (not WM_PAINT) and WM_PRINTCLIENT for the listbox child control. I have intercepted these and turned of the PRF_NONCLIENT bit before calling the default window proc, but it makes no difference. If you suppress the processing of these two messages, the listbox portion of the control doesn't get painted at all.

I also tried removing the WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE bit from the combo box's style. Again, no difference. The listbox itself has no border-related styles.

Any ideas? I could draw the whole thing myself, but I'd rather not have to. I want Windows to draw the content but not the border and shadow.

C++, straight Windows API, no MFC, WPF or anything else.

TIA

Comment: I'm pretty sure the frame and shadow is the non-client area of the list box window, painted in its `WM_NCPAINT` handler. This is a separate window from that of the combo box; changing the style on the combo box's window won't help any. You can obtain an `HWND` of the list box with `CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO`

Comment: Thanks, but it's not WM_NCPAINT. You can suppress WM_NCPAINT on the listbox entirely and it doesn't make any difference. The painting is occurring in WM_PRINT and WM_PRINTCLIENT (that's for the listbox, not the combo box itself). If you suppress these, the listbox doesn't get painted at all. I've added notes to the question.

Comment: You could try sub-classing the dropdown and handling `WM_NCCALCSIZE` to effectively remove the non-client area.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Good idea, but unfortunately that doesn't work either. I'm beginning to think that Windows is either ignoring the client/nonclient distinction or is drawing the border and shadow outside of the window. This is getting annoying.

Comment: Well the shadow is almost certainly due to the `CS_DROPSHADOW` class style which is indeed outside the window bounds. The border though I would have expected was non-client.

Comment: Wow, it's been so long since I used CS_DROPSHADOW that I'd completely forgotten about it. Removing that eliminates the shadow--thanks! I've determined that the border is indeed normally drawn in the nonclient area, but if I expand the client area to the full window, it gets drawn anyway.